# ssrs local report using a dataset embedded in rdl file

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I've searched answer for my problem but not found one.
I have .rdl report with embedded dataset lets call it DataSet1.
What I am trying to do is to use DataSet1 which has connection information and embedded stored procedure, and not to use new dataset lets call it DataSet2 which I need to provide through my mvc project. It gives me "ReportProcessingException: Cannot create a data reader for dataset 'DataSet1'". Similar report is set to Report Server and called through aspx page for preview and works perfectly. All I want is to give my report parameters as I done for other report. I don't need to preview it just to run it and save it. Does anyone knows how to solve this? Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109.aspx), this is not possible.
"The Query element is optional in an RDLC file. This element is ignored by the ReportViewer control because the ReportViewer control does not perform any data processing in local processing mode, but uses data that the host application supplies."